# I want to open vim and see my ":" commands from a previous session. Is that possible?

Tags: vim, ubuntu, command

When i open a file in vim I usually press, by reflex, the colon to see a list of previous commands, but its empty. How can I get my previous command history.

Comment: Is your Vim compiled with `cmdline_hist`? (Check `vim --version` for `+cmdline_hist`)

Answer (score 12):

`:history` should do what you want.

Comment: Even better for browsing _and recall_, is `q:`.

Answer (score 2):

`q:` would be better. it will display a list of commands, and you can press `j`or`k`for motion,then`enter` to run a selected one.